# T-shirt Designer Block Code insert in CMS page of Magento

Tags: magento

When i was installed magento shirtdesigner module by Magento connect , it was showing successfully installation. I think it has okay. My version was ver. 1.7.0.0

I am newer in Magento. I didn't know exactly which page call CMS-page? In admin Panel, for Shirtnetwork Configuration i got a message like "To use shirtdesigner place the following text in your CMS-page:

`{{block type="Aggrosoft_Shirtnetwork/shirtdesigner" name="snw_designer" template="shirtnetwork/shirtdesigner.phtml"}}` .

Which page i will insert this code? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in any CMS page you like.  Then, when you visit that CMS page on the frontend, the 'shirtdesigner' should appear.

Comment: Can you tell me this block code format from "{{block type="Aggrosoft_Shirtnetwork/shirtdesigner" name="snw_designer" template="shirtnetwork/shirtdesigner.phtml"}}"

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you mean.